# Can I use homebrew to compile static binaries with all dependency on macOS

Tags: macos

I would like to compile a binary that is portable like a "normal" macOS bundle app.

For example using https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/cherrytree to create a macOS app that I can then share on a computer that do not have brew.

I know I can compile it using gcc directly. But is their a way to automatize library download and statically link those to the target binary?

I thought someone may have extended homebrew to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I am also trying to create an app bundle which uses Homebrew packages but does not require other users to have Homebrew. The best I have been able to do so far is to install Homebrew inside the app bundle, for example, into a folder

/Applications/myApp.app/Contents/Homebrew

This has a big downside - it takes up a huge amount of disk space, of which only a small fraction is needed at runtime. You can clean it out by hand some after building, but it's painful.

Homebrew says installing into non default location is not officially supported, but it has been working OK. OTOH, the other Mac package manager, MacPorts, does officially support arbitrary install locations, but it doesn't actually work. Go figure...

Comment: Is this an attempt to provie an answer according to [answer] to the question at the top of this page? It does not look like that, but if it is then please [edit] to make that more obvious. Otherwise please delete this.